# Thunar doesn't show any RabbitVCS emblems

Tags: xubuntu, thunar, rabbitvcs

I'm using Xubuntu 12.04 and installed RabbitVCS v0.15.0.5 for Thunar from the PPA. Unfortunately, there are no svn status emblems on my folders in Thunar. I already tried to update the icon cache as explained [here](http://wiki.rabbitvcs.org/wiki/support/faq#troubleshooting).

Did the emblems ever work in Thunar? I'm not really sure, because usually RabbitVCS is used together with Nautilus.

Comment: I don't think Thunar supports custom emblems as of yet.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 12.04 (unity) and installed the latest thunar (1.6) with the xubuntu ppas. I have the same problem with thunar not showing the emblems on the folders/files. It does show rabbitvcs in the right-click context menu of options at least. Would love to know the solution

Answer (score 1):

Did you do [this](http://wiki.rabbitvcs.org/wiki/install/ubuntu) . It says "If you are using the Xubuntu distro, then you probably only have Thunar installed (without Nautilus). Besides rabbitvcs-thunar and rabbitvcs-cli, you also need to install an extra package".

Worked very well for me :)

Comment: To make this answer more useful, please indicate exactly which packages you installed in order to solve that issue.

Comment: The extra package is `thunar-vcs-plugin`. Thunar keeps crashing for me with RabbitVCS enabled though.