# Thunar RabbitVCS - Missing Emblems

Tags: 12.04, svn, thunar, rabbitvcs, emblem

I am running Desktop Ubuntu 12.04 64bit and have installed rabbitvcs-thunar ([through this tutorial](http://tutorialforlinux.blogspot.com/2013/08/tutorial-install-rabbitvcs-in-ubuntu.html)). The context menu to perform RabbitVCS operations is working, but the most important feature, status emblems is not. I have none of the visual indicators showing me if a file is changed as shown below when comparing thunar (left) against nautilus (right) in the same folder.
[image: View of Tunar (left) against Nautilus (right), both with rabbitvcs integration]

I started Thunar with debug output to see if anything had gone wrong, but it doesn't appear to be the case.

```
stuart@office-tower:$ THUNARX_PYTHON_DEBUG=all Thunar
thunar_extension_initialize: entered
thunarx_python_load_dir: entered dirname=/usr/share/thunarx-python/extensions
thunarx_python_init_python: entered
thunarx-python: g_module_open /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
thunarx-python: Py_Initialize
thunarx-python: PySys_SetArgv
thunarx-python: Sanitizing python sys.path
thunarx-python: pygtk.require("2.0")
thunarx-python: init_pygobject
thunarx-python: init_pygtk
thunarx-python: pyg_enable_threads
thunarx-python: sys.path.insert(0, ...)
thunarx-python: import thunarx
thunarx_python_object_get_type: entered type=RabbitVCS
thunarx-python: python modules loaded
thunarx_python_load_dir: entered dirname=/home/stuart/.local/share/thunarx-python/extensions
thunarx_python_load_dir: entered dirname=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/thunarx-2/python
thunar_extension_list_types: entered
```

Please note that I already know that this question is very similar to: [Thunar doesn't show any RabbitVCS emblems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170742/thunar-doesnt-show-any-rabbitvcs-emblems). However, this is for Ubuntu and not Xubuntu and I have the strong impression that this may be lead to the cause of the problem and require a different solution.

Comment: Well, the post that you linked to points to installing `thunar-vcs-plugin`. And additionally, it talks about `rabbitvcs-thunar`. Did you install those packages?

Comment: @landroni yes of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rabbitvcs-thunar does not support emblems, yet.

I spotted that http://blog.rabbitvcs.org/archives/178 states:

> there will be no emblem support for the foreseeable future

I had a quick look at the source code from around that date (https://code.google.com/p/rabbitvcs/source/browse/trunk/rabbitvcs/lib/extensions/thunar/RabbitVCS.py?spec=svn2145&r=2145) and compared it to the current versions (https://code.google.com/p/rabbitvcs/source/browse/trunk/clients/thunar/RabbitVCS.py) and can see there has been no additional work for the emblem handling.

Comment: Although this isn't the answer I was looking for at least I'm pretty sure it is unfortunately "the answer". Thank you for delving into it.